How should I avoid the weird stretching that comes with a projection matrix?
I have an x+ forward matrix defined with the following funciton:
infinite_perspective_projection :: (matrix : *mat4, fovX : float32, aspectRatio : float32, nearClip : float, $clear := true) {
    #if clear {
        matrix.* = mat4.{};
    }

    oneOverTanFovXOver2 := 1. / tan(fovX * 0.5);

    matrix.coef[0][0] = oneOverTanFovXOver2;
    matrix.coef[1][1] = aspectRatio * oneOverTanFovXOver2;
    matrix.coef[2][3] = nearClip;
    matrix.coef[3][2] = 1.;
}
// call to this function
infinite_perspective_projection(*projection,camera.fovy,xx ( r.pipeline.Extent.width / r.pipeline.Extent.height ), camera.eye.z); 

There's only one problem with this though, it creates a weird stretching when rotating, which as you can imagine is not optimal for viewing 3d models


How are you applying the rotation? You mention it's an x+ forward matrix, which as far as I'm aware is not often the case (I've only seen z+ and z- forward matrices before). If you are using a library to do the math, is there a chance that library expects one of those matrices instead?

The usual perspective distortion comes from having a field of view value too large for the viewing conditions. To get a correct, undistorted picture from a given viewpoint, the field of view angle should match the angle the viewer needs to sweep their eyes through to look from one edge of the viewport to the other, given the distance of their eyes from the screen. You can fudge this a bit to see more, but too much will start looking weird. Have you tried lowering your fovX value?

@DMGregory I will try that thank you for that advice

@DMGregory the stretching persists
